# matplotlib should print 5 images from a different subdirectory in each row but in first row only shows 4

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a directory (sdir) with 23 sub directories. Each sub directory has about 100 jpg image files. I want to go to each subdirectory and display the first 5 images in a row using matplotlib,
then go to the next sub directory and plot the first 5 images from that subdirectory in the second row of the plot. etc. So in the end there would be 23 rows with 5 images per row and each row contains 5 images from a specific sub directory. For the first row in the plot, it plots the first 4 images of the first sub directory ( not the first 5 as I expected) and 1 image from the second sub directory. After that it produces 5 images from each sub directory as expected. Why does it only produce 4 images for the first sub directory? Code is shown below:

```
sdir=r'../input/dermnet/train'
plt.figure(figsize=(20,80))
classlist=sorted(os.listdir(sdir))
row =0
for klass in classlist:
    classpath=os.path.join(sdir,klass) # path to sub directory
    flist=os.listdir(classpath) # list of sub directories
    for i, f in enumerate(flist): # enumerate files in each sub directory
        if i <5:
            fpath=os.path.join(classpath,f)
            img=plt.imread(fpath)
            plt.title(klass[:15], color='blue', fontsize=12)
            print(i, row, row +i +1, img.shape, klass) # check if i, row and row + i +1 are correct, also shape say img was read in
            plt.subplot(23,5, row + i + 1 ) # 23 rows, one for each sub directory, 5 images per sub directory
            plt.imshow(img) # get the images plotted
        else:
            row +=5 # increment row by 5 to start next row
            break # break after first 5 images from a sub directory are plotted and go one to the next sub directory
plt.show()  # show all the images
```

The printed out values for i, row and row + i +1  and the sub directory name appear to be correct as shown below:

```
  i     row   row + i + 1   klass (subdir name)
  0      0        1           a
  1      0        2           a
  2      0        3           a
  3      0        4           a
  4      0        5           a
  0      5        6           b
  1      5        7           b
 etc     etc      etc         etc
```

The image shapes I printed out were correct so plt.imread successfully read in each image. I thought at first the 5th image in the first sub directory might be invalid but that is not the case. Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is causing this problem, but whenever I use subplots I prefer to specify explicitly which axes I want something plotted in using `fig, ax = plt.subplots(23, 5, figsize=(20,80))` and `ax[row,i].imshow(img)`

```
sdir=r'../input/dermnet/train'
fig, ax = plt.subplots(23, 5, figsize=(20,80))
classlist=sorted(os.listdir(sdir))
row =0
for klass in classlist:
    classpath=os.path.join(sdir,klass) # path to sub directory
    flist=os.listdir(classpath) # list of sub directories
    for i, f in enumerate(flist): # enumerate files in each sub directory
        if i <5:
            fpath=os.path.join(classpath,f)
            img=plt.imread(fpath)
            #plt.title(klass[:15], color='blue', fontsize=12)
            print(i, row, row +i +1, img.shape, klass) # check if i, row and row + i +1 are correct, also shape say img was read in
            #plt.subplot(23,5, row + i + 1 ) # 23 rows, one for each sub directory, 5 images per sub directory
            ax[row,i].imshow(img) # get the images plotted
            ax[row,i].set_title(klass[:15], color='blue', fontsize=12)
        else:
            row +=5 # increment row by 5 to start next row
            break # break after first 5 images from a sub directory are plotted and go one to the next sub directory
plt.show()  # show all the images
```